# Failed to create COM object Rfc2898DeriveBytes

Tags: php, .net, com

I’m trying to create System.Security.Cryptography.Rfc2898DeriveBytes object in php
so I wrote:

```
$obj = new COM('System.Security.Cryptography.Rfc2898DeriveBytes');
```

but I got:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception ‘com_exception’ with message ‘Failed
>   to create COM object
>   `System.Security.Cryptography.Rfc2898DeriveBytes’: Invalid syntax

what is wrong with this code?

Answer (score 0):

Did you read the relevant docs?
[PHP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.com.php):

> The COM class allows you to instantiate an OLE compatible COM
>   object...

What makes you think `System.Security.Cryptography.Rfc2898DeriveBytes` is an OLE compatible COM type? It isn't.

It is a .NET managed class. Although it carries the `ComVisible` attribute this doesn't make it an OLE compatible COM type which you can instantiate using COM. In particular, it doesn't have a default constructor, so [it is mapped to a **noncreateable** coclass](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/46f8ac6z.aspx) in the COM type library generated when the .NET assembly is registered with COM. Consequently it can't be instantiated using any COM-based mechanism - only by managed code calling one of its constructors. Besides which its namespace-qualified name is too long to be a COM ProgId.

If you want to exploit this .NET class via the PHP COM class, you could write a wrapper class in .NET managed code which is OLE compatible as well as ComVisible with a default constructor, and forward your calls through that.

Comment: the "wrapper class" is the thing I'm trying to get rid of, thanks anyway.